# Showing link target in not visible iframe?

Tags: redirect, iframe

I have a link, it looks like that:

```
<a href="someplace.html" target="shop">link text</a>
```

The target (shop) is an iframe with the name *shop*. Clicking the link and showing someplace.html in the iframe only works, if the page that contains the iframe is already loaded.

So my problem is, how can I make it work even if the page that contains the iframe is not loaded? I tried loading the page with the iframe by redirecting to it when the link was clicked using its onclick, that worked, but I still have to load someplace.html afterwards and this is where I am stuck.

Any ideas how to solve that? I can use jQuery or plain JavaScript ... doesnt matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a link with a target "shop", you must have a iframe called "shop". It is possible to load the iframe with a blank page if there is no initial content.